# Error: Expression expected before 'i' in C

Tags: c, struct

I have written a C code to accept values via an array of structures which asks the user in the main function to choose whether he/she wants to input char or int values and sort the array via insertion sort and print it, but I am getting an
**error from the compiler**: {error]: expected expression before i

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int n;

 typedef struct ls{
    int a;
    char l;
 }i[50],ls;

 int main(){

    printf("Enter the value\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ls int1;
    
    int ans;
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("1.)integer sort \n2.)Characrter sort\n");
    scanf("%d",&ans);
    if(ans==1){
        intSort(i.a);
    }
    else if(ans==2){
        charSort(i.l);
    }
    else{
        exit(0);
    }
    int ans1;
    printf("Would you like to print the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&ans1);
    if(ans==1 && ans1==1){
        display(i.a);
    }
    else{
        display(i.l);
    }
}
int intSort(int a[]){
    int j;
    printf("Enter the values into the array \n");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        
        scanf("%d",&a[j]);
    }
    
    //  insertion sort function call
    insertionSort(a);
    return 1;
}

int charSort(char a[]){
    int j;
    printf("Enter the values into the array \n");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        
        scanf(" %c",&a[j]);
    }
    insertionSort(a);
    return a;
}
int insertionSort(int a[]){
    int temp,i,j;
    
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        
        temp= a[i];
        j=i-1;
    }
    while(j>=0 && temp<a[j]){
        a[j+1]=a[j];
        j-=1;
    }
    a[j+1]=temp;

    return 1;
}
int display(int a[]){
    int i;
    printf("Sorted array:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit question to indicate the error line, please.

Comment: In `main()`, `i` is a type, not a variable.  You have `typedef struct ls { … } i[50], ls;`, which defines `i` as an alias for the type 'array of 50 `struct ls`'.  You can't pass a type to a function, hence the error messages.  If you want `i` to be a variable that is an array of 50 structures, then you need to separate it from the `typedef` — `typedef struct ls { … } ls; static ls i[50];` would work.  (Since there's no evidence you are using multiple files, `static` is reasonable, though omitting `static` also works.)

Comment: You are using `i` as if it is a variable but it's not! `i` is a type due to the use of `typedef ...` So if you really want `i` to be a type, you need to define variables of that type afterwards - like `i i_variable;`. Alternatively you shouldn't define `i` as a type but as a global variable. Unfortunately it's hard to tell what you actually want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the type incorrectly. If I understand correctly, you want do have a typedef `ls` and then initialize an array of your newly defined structures. You would want to do something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ls {
  int a;
  char l;
} ls;

int main() {
        int i;
        ls *array_of_ls = malloc(50*sizeof(*array_of_ls));
        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                array_of_ls[i].a = i;
                array_of_ls[i].l = 65+i;
                printf("ls[%d] = (%d, %c)\n", i, array_of_ls[i].a, array_of_ls[i].l);
        }
        free(array_of_ls);
}
```

Of course, make sure you handle exceptions, etc. But this should get you going.

Comment: I suspect that the OP hasn't learned about dynamic memory allocation yet.  This answer may be more complex than they can cope with at the moment.  You're right that `i` in the OP's code is probably meant to be a variable, not a type.  However, greater fidelity to the OP's code would create a static array `static struct ls i[50];` (or `static ls i[50];`) and proceed from there.

Comment: Yep, a good point. Perhaps the best lesson learned here is to break the code into simple, small functional units that actually compile/work, and then proceed to combine them into a larger unit.

Comment: ya you're right @JonathanLeffler i am learning dynamic memory allocation and data structures at the moment, i came across this problem thought of asking on the forum instead, thanks for the solution btw@Andrej Prsa.